# Possible conflict between nicematrix and gensymb (and an additional package)

Tags: math-mode, symbols, incompatibility, nicematrix

I noticed an interesting conflict between several packages. I was using symbols from `gensymb` in math mode, but this seemed to cause problems in a very particular scenario. This seems to be the case for any document class.

When I call `\usepackage{nicematrix}` before `\usepackage{gensymb}` AND call `\usepackage` on any of the following packages: `(textcomp,xfrac,chemmacros)`, I run into problems when trying to place symbols from `gensymb` into math mode. The error reads `"\textfont 4 is undefined (character W). $\ohm$"` or `"\textfont 4 is undefined (character �). $\degree$"`.

I just updated to TeX Live 2023 (full scheme) and updated my packages using tlmgr. I however had the same problems in the 2022 version as well.

Attached is a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{gensymb}

%Add any of these three packages and the gensymb symbols (\degree,\ohm) do not work in math mode if nicematrix is situated before gensymb. If nicematrix is placed after gensymb, no problems arise.
\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{xfrac}
%\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}
\degree
$\degree$

\ohm
$\ohm$

\end{document}
```

I already found a workaround by placing `\usepackage{nicematrix}` after `\usepackage{gensymb}` but I was interested if anyone had a clue as to what was causing this problem.

Here is also the full log output:

```
    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.4.14)  14 APR 2023 17:42
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**testitesti.tex
(./testitesti.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-03-30>
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/letter.cls
Document Class: letter 2021/12/07 v1.3c Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\longindentation=\dimen140
\indentedwidth=\dimen141
\labelcount=\count185
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2b Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen142
\Gin@req@width=\dimen143
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks17
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen144
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen145
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box51
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)
Package: pgfrcs 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks18
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks19

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslibraryfil
tered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks20
))
\pgf@x=\dimen146
\pgf@y=\dimen147
\pgf@xa=\dimen148
\pgf@ya=\dimen149
\pgf@xb=\dimen150
\pgf@yb=\dimen151
\pgf@xc=\dimen152
\pgf@yc=\dimen153
\pgf@xd=\dimen154
\pgf@yd=\dimen155
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read2
\c@pgf@counta=\count186
\c@pgf@countb=\count187
\c@pgf@countc=\count188
\c@pgf@countd=\count189
\t@pgf@toka=\toks21
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks22
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks23
\pgf@sys@id@count=\count190

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.d
ef
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-p
df.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.
code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count191
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count192
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.
code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2022/06/12 v2.14 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 227.

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1374.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1375.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1376.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen156
\pgfmath@count=\count193
\pgfmath@box=\box52
\pgfmath@toks=\toks24
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks25
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks26
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count194
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen157
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen158
\pgf@picminy=\dimen159
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen160
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen161
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen162
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen163
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen164
\pgf@xx=\dimen165
\pgf@xy=\dimen166
\pgf@yx=\dimen167
\pgf@yy=\dimen168
\pgf@zx=\dimen169
\pgf@zy=\dimen170
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconst
ruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen171
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen172
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage
.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen173
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen174
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfpic=\box53
\pgf@hbox=\box54
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box55
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count195
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicst
ate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen175
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransform
ations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen176
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen177
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen178
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.c
ode.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathproce
ssing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen179
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@max=\dimen180
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count196
\pgf@shadingcount=\count197
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box56
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretranspare
ncy.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.
code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.
tex
File: pgfcorerdf.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.cod
e.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box57
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2023-03-30 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2023-03-30 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count198
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box58
))
Package: l3keys2e 2023-02-02 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
Package: nicematrix 2023/03/31 v6.17 Enhanced arrays with the help of PGF/TikZ
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty
Package: array 2022/09/04 v2.5g Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen181
\ar@mcellbox=\box59
\extrarowheight=\dimen182
\NC@list=\toks27
\extratabsurround=\skip48
\backup@length=\skip49
\ar@cellbox=\box60
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2022/04/08 v2.17n AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip50

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks28
\ex@=\dimen183
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen184
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count199
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count266
\leftroot@=\count267
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \colon on input line 410.
\classnum@=\count268
\DOTSCASE@=\count269
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box61
\strutbox@=\box62
LaTeX Info: Redefining \big on input line 722.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Big on input line 723.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bigg on input line 724.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Bigg on input line 725.
\big@size=\dimen185
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count270
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bmod on input line 905.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pmod on input line 910.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \smash on input line 940.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \relbar on input line 970.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Relbar on input line 971.
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count271
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count272
\dspbrk@lvl=\count273
\tag@help=\toks29
\row@=\count274
\column@=\count275
\maxfields@=\count276
\andhelp@=\toks30
\eqnshift@=\dimen186
\alignsep@=\dimen187
\tagshift@=\dimen188
\tagwidth@=\dimen189
\totwidth@=\dimen190
\lineht@=\dimen191
\@envbody=\toks31
\multlinegap=\skip51
\multlinetaggap=\skip52
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks32
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2953.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2954.
)
\g__nicematrix_env_int=\count277
\g__nicematrix_NiceMatrixBlock_int=\count278
\l__nicematrix_note_in_caption_int=\count279
\l__nicematrix_columns_width_dim=\dimen192
\l__nicematrix_col_width_dim=\dimen193
\g__nicematrix_row_total_int=\count280
\g__nicematrix_col_total_int=\count281
\g__nicematrix_last_row_node_int=\count282
\l__nicematrix_key_nb_rows_int=\count283
\g__nicematrix_blocks_wd_dim=\dimen194
\g__nicematrix_blocks_ht_dim=\dimen195
\g__nicematrix_blocks_dp_dim=\dimen196
\l__nicematrix_width_dim=\dimen197
\l__nicematrix_tabular_width_dim=\dimen198
\l__nicematrix_rule_width_dim=\dimen199
\l__nicematrix_old_iRow_int=\count284
\l__nicematrix_old_jCol_int=\count285
\g__nicematrix_total_X_weight_int=\count286
\l__nicematrix_X_columns_dim=\dimen256
\l__nicematrix_x_initial_dim=\dimen257
\l__nicematrix_y_initial_dim=\dimen258
\l__nicematrix_x_final_dim=\dimen259
\l__nicematrix_y_final_dim=\dimen260
\l__nicematrix_tmpc_dim=\dimen261
\l__nicematrix_tmpd_dim=\dimen262
\g__nicematrix_width_last_col_dim=\dimen263
\g__nicematrix_width_first_col_dim=\dimen264
\l__nicematrix_row_min_int=\count287
\l__nicematrix_row_max_int=\count288
\l__nicematrix_col_min_int=\count289
\l__nicematrix_col_max_int=\count290
\g__nicematrix_static_num_of_col_int=\count291
\l__nicematrix_rounded_corners_dim=\dimen265
\l__nicematrix_line_width_dim=\dimen266
\g__nicematrix_block_box_int=\count292
\l__nicematrix_submatrix_extra_height_dim=\dimen267
\l__nicematrix_submatrix_left_xshift_dim=\dimen268
\l__nicematrix_submatrix_right_xshift_dim=\dimen269
\l__nicematrix_first_row_int=\count293
\l__nicematrix_first_col_int=\count294
\l__nicematrix_last_row_int=\count295
\l__nicematrix_last_col_int=\count296
\c@tabularnote=\count297
\c@nicematrix_draft=\count298
\l__nicematrix_cell_space_top_limit_dim=\dimen270
\l__nicematrix_cell_space_bottom_limit_dim=\dimen271
\l__nicematrix_xdots_inter_dim=\dimen272
\l__nicematrix_xdots_shorten_start_dim=\dimen273
\l__nicematrix_xdots_shorten_end_dim=\dimen274
\l__nicematrix_xdots_radius_dim=\dimen275
\l__nicematrix_notes_above_space_dim=\dimen276
\l__nicematrix_left_margin_dim=\dimen277
\l__nicematrix_right_margin_dim=\dimen278
\l__nicematrix_extra_left_margin_dim=\dimen279
\l__nicematrix_extra_right_margin_dim=\dimen280
\c__nicematrix_max_l_dim=\dimen281
\l__nicematrix_position_int=\count299
\l__nicematrix_start_int=\count300
\l__nicematrix_multiplicity_int=\count301
\l__nicematrix_brace_yshift_dim=\dimen282
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/gensymb/gensymb.sty
Package: gensymb 2022/10/17 v1.0.2 (KJH)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
)
(build/testitesti.aux)
\openout1 = `testitesti.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count302
\scratchdimen=\dimen283
\scratchbox=\box63
\nofMPsegments=\count303
\nofMParguments=\count304
\everyMPshowfont=\toks33
\MPscratchCnt=\count305
\MPscratchDim=\dimen284
\MPnumerator=\count306
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count307
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks34
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
\symgns@font=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `gns@font' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TS1/cmr/m/n --> TS1/cmr/b/n on input line 12.
Package gensymb Info: Math companion symbols declared on input line 12.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \degree on input line 12.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \celsius on input line 12.
Package gensymb Info: Using text companion symbols for \degree, \celsius and \p
erthousand on input line 12.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ohm on input line 12.
Package gensymb Info: Using \textohm for \ohm on input line 12.
Package gensymb Info: Using \textmu for \micro on input line 12.

! \textfont 4 is undefined (character �).
l.14 $\degree$
              
Somewhere in the math formula just ended, you used the
stated character from an undefined font family. For example,
plain TeX doesn't allow \it or \sl in subscripts. Proceed,
and I'll try to forget that I needed that character.

! \textfont 4 is undefined (character W).
l.17 $\ohm$
           
Somewhere in the math formula just ended, you used the
stated character from an undefined font family. For example,
plain TeX doesn't allow \it or \sl in subscripts. Proceed,
and I'll try to forget that I needed that character.

[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}{/usr/loc
al/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-ts1.enc}]
(build/testitesti.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 11783 strings out of 476017
 263900 string characters out of 5789774
 1850666 words of memory out of 5000000
 32087 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 513076 words of font info for 35 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 87i,6n,90p,431b,110s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
</usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/
amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm
-super/sfrm1000.pfb>
Output written on build/testitesti.pdf (1 page, 12159 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 22 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 14 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 13 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT : This bug of `nicematrix` has been solved in the version 6.18 2023-04-19.

---

The reason is that `nicematrix` uses a specific a detail of the implementation of `{array}` of `array` (in order to detect empty cells --- that is to say cells with only spaces between the `&`--- in some types of columns.)

In order to detect whether `{array}` has been changed, a test is done (by composing a small tabular in a scratch box at the beginning of the document).

That's the origin of the incompatibility. Maybe I will delete that test in a future version (I'm not sure if it was a good idea).

For the moment, there is a key at load-time to disable that test:

`\usepackage[no-test-for-array]{nicematrix}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[no-test-for-array]{nicematrix}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{gensymb}

%Add any of these three packages and the gensymb symbols (\degree,\ohm) do not work in math mode if nicematrix is situated before gensymb. If nicematrix is placed after gensymb, no problem arises.
\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{xfrac}
%\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}
\degree
$\degree$

\ohm
$\ohm$

\end{document}
```

I will (at least) add a warning in the documentation of `nicematrix`.

Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: the test is not so much a problem, but you shouldn't do typesetting in the begindocument hook (and storing something in a box is typesetting!) as font setup is not yet finished, delay the test to begindocument/after.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I will do that. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: Why does this cause problems with \degree and \ohm specifically and not with most other symbols?